# Using defined constants in functions and structs without them going blank (Swift)

Tags: function, class, swift, struct, constants

Ok, so im starting to learn programming using swift and I know more than the basics but I can't figure this out.
So if I'm trying to make a function with some stablished constant values and some variables it seems like I can't define constants without them acting like variables.
For example, here I want to make a function for the Area of a Circle:

```
func CircleArea(radius: Int) {
  println(radius*radius*3.1415926)
}
```

I also tried

```
struct Circle {
  let pi = 3.1415926
  var radius: Int

  func CircleArea(pi: Int, radius: Int) {
    println(radius*radius*pi)
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a predefined constant `M_PI`, so you don't have to define your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply Int times Double. You need to convert your Int to Double first:

```
println( Double(radius*radius)*3.1415926 )

func circleArea(radius: Int) -> Double {
    return Double(radius*radius) * M_PI
}
```

Note: You should name your methods starting with a lowercase letter. For the mathematical pi value you can use M_PI (Double)

Comment: Thanks! i hadn't notice that